# How to install Jasmin: the javascript test tool on Velocity project

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, velocity, jasmine

I am searching the web for installing jasmine in order to test my javascript files. Most places assumes I will install it as a gem in a ruby project. But I am running velocity / Java project.

How do I install it? And is there a nice and easy guide to explain step-by-step how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Maven plugin for that. Here's an example of how to use it:

First, in you project's POM, [configure the plugin to be executed](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-platform/blob/master/xwiki-platform-core/xwiki-platform-web/pom.xml#L72-L95):

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2-beta-5</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <sourceIncludes>
        <!-- relative to $jsSrcDir, defined further down -->
        <include>js/prototype/prototype.js</include>
        <include>uicomponents/widgets/list/xlist.js</include>
        <include>uicomponents/suggest/suggest.js</include>
        <include>uicomponents/model/entityReference.js</include>
      </sourceIncludes>
      <specIncludes>
        <!-- relative to src/test/javascript/ -->
        <include>spec/**/*.js</include>
      </specIncludes>
      <jsSrcDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources</jsSrcDir>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Then write specifications, in [`src/test/javascript/spec/`](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-platform/tree/master/xwiki-platform-core/xwiki-platform-web/src/test/javascript/spec), using Jasmine's standards.

Next time you `mvn install` your project, Jasmine tests will be executed as well, failing the build if something is wrong.